# How to remove NavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

In my app I am using a NavigationController to display a SlideView by using following code

```
func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SlideViewController) {
    sidePanelController.delegate = centerViewController
    let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sidePanelController)
    view.insertSubview(navigationController.view, atIndex: 0)
    addChildViewController(navigationController)
    navigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

So the centerViewController is my mainViewController. After the usage of this side panel, I need to remove it from my MainView. Currently I am using code

```
self.leftViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
self.leftViewController = nil;
```

The view inside the NavigationController is removed by this code, but the navigation bar and other container layers are still there. 
How to remove whole navigation controller?

Comment: do you have navigation controller for self.leftViewController ?. How did you added self.leftViewController ?

Comment: creating a variable by 
var leftViewController: SlideViewController?
and adding it by using
func addLeftPanelViewController() {
        if (leftViewController == nil) {
            leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
            addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
        }
    }